# Como usa correctamente FileStream

Tags: c#, imagen, responsive, input-type, asp.net-core-mvc

He desarrollado una app web-responsive en la que requiere copiar una imagen capturada desde el celular y copiarla en una ruta de un servidor (para el caso de pruebas estoy usando la ip de mi maquina como http://192.168.5.37/ + la ruta donde quiero guardar + nombredelaimagen ), para esto uso FileStream pero al instanciarlo me adiciona la ruta actual de mi proyecto mas la ruta del servidor donde se va a copiar la imagen, lo que me genera error, entonces la ruta final me queda

```
C:\Proyectos\Culinaria\WebRepartidor\WebRepartidor\WebRepartidor\http:\192.168.5.37\c:\var\catering\documentos\WebRepartidor\PerritoBonito.jpg''
```

En lugar de

```
http:\192.168.5.37\c:\var\catering\documentos\WebRepartidor\PerritoBonito.jpg'' que es la ruta correcta
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mio metodo recibo como parametro la imagen

```
public IActionResult RecordIncidents(IncidentsTracking segIncidents,
                                     IFormFile mypic) {
  if (mypic != null && mypic.Length > 0) {
    string rutaHTTP = "http://192.168.5.37/" +
                      "c:/var/catering/documentos/WebRepartidor/imagen.jgp";
    using (var stream = new FileStream(rutaHTTP, FileMode.Open)) {
      mypic.CopyTo(stream);
    }
  }
```

¿Que puedo hacer hacer para solventar, que usar en lugar de File Stream?

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira yo he estado haciendo algo parecido y me funciona, puedes acomodarlo a tus necesidades

```
private void CopiarFotos()
{
    string carpetaOrigen = @"\\SRVSAP1\Fotos Empleados"; // Ruta de la carpeta en red de origen

    string Ruta_Formato;
    string Ruta = Application.StartupPath.ToString();
    Ruta_Formato = Path.Combine(Ruta, "Fotos"); // Combinar la ruta de la aplicación con "Fotos"
    string carpetaDestino = Ruta_Formato; // Ruta de la carpeta local de destino

    try
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(carpetaDestino))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(carpetaDestino); // Crea la carpeta si no existe
        }

        string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(carpetaOrigen);

        foreach (string archivo in archivos)
        {
            string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(archivo);
            string destinoArchivo = Path.Combine(carpetaDestino, nombreArchivo);

            if (!File.Exists(destinoArchivo))
            {
                File.Copy(archivo, destinoArchivo);
            }
        }

        // MessageBox.Show("Archivos copiados con éxito.", "Éxito");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Bienvenido ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Les quiero dejar por acá la solución que a mi funcionó

En mi COntroller recibo el objeto con todas las propriedades de una entidad y el control input type file que es donde tengo la imagen

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RecordIncidents(IncidentsTracking segIncidents, [FromForm]  IFormFile mypic)
    {
      
        string dominioPublico = (_configuration["DominioPublico:Dominio"]);
        string path = (_configuration["DominioPublico:Path"]);

        string nameImagen = (mypic.FileName).ToString();
        DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.Now;
        Calendar calendario = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
        int numeroSemana = calendario.GetWeekOfYear(fechaActual, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        
        IncidentsTracking ObjIncidentsTraking = new IncidentsTracking();
        ObjIncidentsTraking.id = null;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.fecha = (DateTime.Today).ToString("d");
        ObjIncidentsTraking.fecha_cierre = null;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.solucion = null;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.actuacion = null;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.estado = "P";
        ObjIncidentsTraking.tipo = "I";
        ObjIncidentsTraking.create_date = (DateTime.Today).ToString("d");
        ObjIncidentsTraking.last_modified_date = (DateTime.Today).ToString("d");
        ObjIncidentsTraking.created_by = TempData["UserName"] as string;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.last_modified_by = TempData["UserName"] as string;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.afiliado_id = TempData["AfiliadoId"] as string;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.empleado_id = null;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.grupo_id = TempData["GrupoId"] as string;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.incidencia_id = segIncidents.incidencia_id;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.miincidencia_id = segIncidents.miincidencia_id;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.maquina_id = "";
        ObjIncidentsTraking.causa = segIncidents.causa;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.revision_rueda = null;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.semana = numeroSemana.ToString();
        ObjIncidentsTraking.areas_id = "20";
        ObjIncidentsTraking.cliente_id = TempData["ClienteId"] as string;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.archivos = ";" + mypic.FileName;
        ObjIncidentsTraking.carpeta = "/var/catering/documentos";
        if (ObjIListIncidentsData.InsertRegIncidents(ObjIncidentsTraking))
        {
            if (mypic != null && mypic.Length > 0)
            {
                var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
                string rutaCompartida = @"\\" + dominioPublico + "\\" + path + "\\";
                dominioPublico = (configuration["DominioPublico:Dominio"]);
                
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(rutaCompartida, mypic.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    mypic.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

            }
                
            TempData["UserName"]= TempData["User_Name_R"] as string;
            TempData["Password"] = TempData["User_Password_R"] as string;
            return RedirectToAction("usersList", "UsersList");
        }
            
        else
            return View();
    }
            
        else
            return View();
    }
}
```

y en mi view

```
<input type="file" id="mypic" name="mypic" accept="image/*" capture="camera"> <canvas id="canvas" style="width:50%; height:50%"></canvas> <br /> <img id="preview" src="Imagen a cargar" style="display:none" />
```

Adicional cree una carpeta compartida en una unidad de red en la que guardaré la foto (imagen) a la que asigné `(Imagenes) z:` y en `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Imagenes`

En mi archivo `appsentting.json` asigne las variables que uso en mi controller

```
"DominioPublico": { "Dominio": "DESKTOP-O08GDD3", "path": "Imagenes" },
```

Comment: Saludos Carmen, todos estos comentarios, inclúyelos en la respuesta (click en Editar). Luego de 24 horas recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta (click en el check del costado).

Comment: Saludos, Freddy! Buenos días!
Listo ya inclui los comentarios en la respuesta.

Comment: excelente, ahora, elimina los comentarios para mantener el orden en el sitio, gracias por la colaboración :D

Comment: Listo Freddy, muchas gracias por todas tus recomenciones y valiosa ayuda que me has brindado
Saludos

Comment: Un gusto colaborar, también al otro usuario que te dio una respuesta fue de gran ayuda :D